# Outlook folder showing incorrect size

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When using Outlook I maintain my folders and clean them out each day. My mailbox has a limit of 200MB (set by employer), my mailbox currently has only 22MB used but on the bottom left hand side of Outlook its shows me I have only 7.9MB free? does anyone know what his is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to purge the deleted items which have not yet been truly deleted (they are kept for a grace period in case you want them back).

Go to Deleted Items. On the Ribbon, click the "Folder" tab. Click "recover deleted items".

Click the "Select All" button at top left of the dialogue box (or use normal multi-select methods eg shift+click to select lots but not all). Click the black X to purge all these items.